# preventDefault stops function from working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery:

```
jQuery('#overlayBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#overlay').css('display','flex');
});
```

If I remove the preventDefault() it works fine but the page jump up to the top as I have a # as the href.  I want to stop the default click behavior but make my overlay show.

How do I do this?

Comment: Could you include more relevant code, or even better make a working snippet of the problem

Comment: any script errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add at the end of function `return false;`

```
jQuery('#overlayBtn').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('#overlay').css('display','flex');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, I will mark it soon as time limit allows.  May I ask why it works?

Comment: The return value of an event handler determines whether or not the default browser behaviour should take place as well. It's almost the same as `e.preventDefault();` : https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation

Answer (score 1):

As another user said before, `return false;` could be the soulution for this case but consider this is not a good practice.

Please refer to the following link to see why you shold't use that line of code: https://web.archive.org/web/20160603125641/http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

In addition, you can use the attribute `href="javascript:void(0)"` to achieve the same result.

Comment: But reliable cross-browser solution (while as `e.preventDefault` fails in IE).